# how to make publisher trusted

Tags: deployment, certificate, publishing, trusted-application

I have:

- server domain, where the application is developed and deployed
- my own machine, not part of the server domain, on which I test the application

When I install the app on my machine - it asks me if I trust the publisher (and whether to continue with installation or not). What I want to achieve is to make the publisher trusted beforehead I run the installation and proceed the installation smoothly without questions about trusting publishers, whatsoever.

For this purpose I have created a self-signed certificate from the server domain (*I tried with  both`.p7b` and `.pfx` types of certificates*), get the certificate file on my testing machine and deploy it (import the certificate in Trusted Publishers (and eventually tried to import it in other directories also).

Despite these actions, when I run the installation, it still asks me whether I trust the publisher.